# Comparable Class

Tags: java, comparable

I've been trying to learn the comparable class for sometime now, I know the correct syntax and the how it is used in most cases. Such as:

```
int result = ObjectA.compareTo(ObjectB);
```

would return a value of 0 if both object is the same; a negative value if object A is less then object B ,or a positive value if A is greater then B.

However when I go to actually write a program that uses the compareTo method, the compiler is saying that it can not find the compareTo method.

my question is: Do I have to directly inherit from the Comparable class in order to use the compareTo method? only reason I'm asking is because you do not have to explicitly inherit methods like toString or equals...because everything inherit from object. Where does CompareTo fall under?

Comment: Note that Comparable is an interface, not a class.

Comment: Now comes a wave of about 15 answers, all saying the same thing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
```

and then declare the `compareTo()` method:

```
public int compareTo(MyClass myClass){
    //compare and return result
}
```

Comment: Well that makes sense, i will accept answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

[`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is an interface, not a class.  So you would implement the interface, not subclass the class.  Additionally, implementing the interface means implementing the `compareTo` method yourself in your implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, it will only work in instances. Don't know if your compare is comparing objects or the classes itself because of your naming. I will assume you are using objects :)
2. The class you want to compare using `#compareTo` MUST implement `Comparable`. Another way to achieve this without having to implement `Comparable` is providing your sort method a `Comparator` expecting your class.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparable` is an interface so you do not "inherit" it (`extends`), but implement it (`implements`).

You can write your own `compareTo` method in your class without specifying the `Comparable` interface, but then the methods in the API won't know if your object meets the contract that `Comparable` enforces. So, you won't be able to use methods like `Arrays.sort()` and the like that expect to work with objects that do enforce `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the objects of your class `A` compared, possibly because you like to *sort* a list of those objects, you need to make the class `A` implement `Comparable` interface.

Once the class `A` implements `Comparable` it must implement and define the behavior of `compareTo`, which is essentially how *you* want two objects of class `A` be compared.

It it this method where you can decide which fields of the class `A` take part in evaluating the *lesser*- or *greaterness* of an object.